# SSRS SQL Query Expression: Display only either negative or positive value, or both

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008

In my SSRS report layout, there is a parameter `@PositiveOrNegative`, with three values `Positive`, `Negative` and `Both`. In my report there is a *column A*. For examples,

1. When I select `Positive` in `@PositiveOrNegative`, *column A* will display **only positive** values.
2. When I select `Negative` in `@PositiveOrNegative`, *column A* will display **only negative values**.
3. When I select `Both` in `@PositiveOrNegative`, *column A* will display **all values**, regardless it is positive or negative.

Can someone write me a query expression for the situation above?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
=Switch(
    Parameters!PositiveOrNegative.Value = "Positive" AND Fields!A.Value > 0, Fields!A.Value,
    Parameters!PositiveOrNegative.Value = "Negative" AND Fields!A.Value < 0, Fields!A.Value,
    Fields!A.Value
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the value expression for the textbox to the following (assuming you want to display 0's as positive):

```
=IIf
    (
        (
                Parameters!PositiveOrNegative.Value = "Positive" And Fields!Column_A.Value >= 0
            Or  Parameters!PositiveOrNegative.Value = "Negative" And Fields!Column_A.Value < 0
            Or  Parameters!PositiveOrNegative.Value = "Both"
        ),
        Fields!Column_A.Value,
        Nothing
    )
```